# Iframe loader with percentage bar

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to show numeric progress bar when iframe (with giving url) is loading using jquery

Comment: I don't think it's possible but you could use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/CPadm/3/

Comment: Not out of the box, as HTTP is stateless. There's no way to know how much data is being retrieved or how far through it is and therefore how long it will take. The best you can do is a perpetual loading indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can **PACE**. You can customize it as per you need even loading of iframe or progress in Numbers or what ever.

Here is complete  [**website**](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)

And for documentation [**click here**](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Actually i am trying to create sitemap for website. I want to show all website contents when it is processing.

Comment: Well this point is totally different from your asked question. Please post another question for different problem.